# Test set correlation decreasing while training set correlation increasing

Tags: neural-network

I'm trainging neural network. My test set correlation is decreasing while training set correlation increases.

**What can be a problem?**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an expected behaviour. You are simply visualizing the **overfitting** of your network. It is trying "to hard" to model your training data and as a result it loses its generalization capabilities (scores on the test data). For this reason you should not train neural networks "to some error on the training set" nor "as long as you can" but instead - work with some more reasonable techniques, like regularization techniques (at least weight decay) and/or early stopping techniques.